# Invoke a lambda function from my HTML code

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I wrote a lambda function. Now I'm trying to invoke it from my HTML. I wrote a JavaScript method that invokes it but it doesn't work.
I added this link to my HTML file

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.10.min.js"></script>
```

And I started the method with:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

This call fails somehow, I don't know why and I don't have a way to debug it.
Do you have some idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

To instantiate an AWS object in the browser, you do not need the require:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
```

You can then `invoke` a Lambda function (if you are authenticated and authorized).

Note: Most of the time it is more appropriate to put the Lambda function behind an API Gateway and invoke it via REST (API Gateway can generate a client for your API for you).

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include sdk script -

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.139.0.min.js"></script>
```

You can see step by step method in AWS documentation -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/browser-invoke-lambda-function-example.html

lastly if you are using API gateway don't forget to enable CORS incase your API gateway and sites domain names are different else you will get some error like -

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://test123.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```